# Pass a vector to a class extending ListActivity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I wrote a class that extends ListActivity for displaying a list in android phone using an array defined in the same class.
I want to call the same class passing a vector or string array and display it.

How to pass and use it???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If the array is just strings, you can pass it in an Intent Extra

**[Intent.putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)**